# Can calendar view of datepicker be manually set in android?

Tags: android, datepicker, calendar

I am developing a perpetual calendar application in android. I need to manually set the position of dates in calendar view of the datepicker upon user's selection of year and month values.

Currently, if I use a datepicker, it shows me with the system's date and months.
How can I customize it for above requirement.

If there is any way of doing it, please suggest, otherwise I am thinking of adding 31 labels for displaying the each date of the month, which I guess is not an appropriate method.

Comment: 31 labels would be overkill, you can use a gridview?

Comment: Can you please provide some more details??  I would have to arrange the dates as per the calculations for a specific month and year. Will that be editable?

Comment: Yes you will get an adapter to customize, however this question is too broad and I cannot support you with a code example. Just try to look for Grid View with custom adapter.

Comment: Also if the only problem you are facing is to set custom dates on the System provided datepicker, refer to the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

use can set the particular date on Datepicker by using DatePicker.setMonth and
DatePicker.setYear methods.

Comment: I guess this will set the calendar to the provided month and year value. I don't want to do that. I want to create my own calendar with my own algorithm, thereby selecting position of date for different combination of months and years. Correct me if I am wrong anywhere.